# Add object in NativeModules

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to use https://github.com/dgladkov/react-native-image-rotate in react-native project

I download it with `yarn add react-native-image-rotate`

I link it with `react-native link`

I import it in my component with `import ImageRotate from 'react-native-image-rotate';`

But when I try to use it I have a `Cannot read property 'rotateImage' of undefined`

I put a break-point in node_modules/react-native-image-rotate/index.js on the line:

`const RCTImageRotateModule = NativeModules.ImageRotateModule;`

And in the object NativeModules there is no ImageRotateModule object.

How Can I add `ImageRotateModule` in `NativeModules` ?

Im using react-native 0.50.3

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
react-native link react-native-image-rotate
```