# require('react-native').NativeModules is an empty object

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, import

In one of the node_modules that I'm using in my project at the top of the file it says:

```js
let RNRandomBytes = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNRandomBytes
```

Unfortunately, it appears that require('react-native').NativeModules is an empty object {}. How can I proceed from here?

The package that I'm trying to use is: 'react-native-secure-randombytes'.

If anyone has experience with this I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add object in NativeModules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713430/add-object-in-nativemodules)

Comment: Thanks, trying that now. I had run "rnpm link", but it's worth trying this.

Comment: Should it be run from the 'react-native-secure-randombytes' directory??

Comment: No, react-native link (and rnpm link) should be run in your project root directory. If you ran rnpm link, this probably isn't the solution unless you ran the command in the wrong directory. Worth trying still to be sure.

Comment: Yeah have tried but to no avail :'(

Comment: Though the error has now moved to a further line at least.

Comment: So maybe this is the solution, will try to continue. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MichaelCheng, do you have any other suggestions that it could be?

Comment: You're not using expo right? Otherwise you can't use native modules

Comment: @MattAft I am using expo unfortunately. So now I'm trying to find pure javascript implementations. I think I'm able to do it. This will be just for a proof of concept anyway so security doesn't have to be top top concern

Comment: @MattAft If you know any pure javascript implementations to sign a transaction, please let me know I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-random-bytes?

Comment: Will give it a go, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way may be it help you

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: when NativeModules is empty, what is solution?

Answer (score -1):

I would do this instead

```
let RNRandomBytes = require('react-native-secure-randombytes')
```

What you're doing means that it's part of the react-native module, which it is not.