# NativeModules is always empty. Visual Studio Code + Windows for iOS?

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I am wondering if there are any developers who develop for iOS using `react-native` using Windows. I have a burning suspicion that there are none. The reason I think that is that I could not find a single example where someone can access the file system of the iOS device with the following development setup:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Code
- Expo app
- iOS (iPhone/iPad)

There are similar questions, but there are no answers that actually work for Windows + VSCode:

- [require('react-native').NativeModules is an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287950/requirereact-native-nativemodules-is-an-empty-object)
- [Add object in NativeModules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713430/add-object-in-nativemodules)

Can someone, please explain if it's possible to use NativeModules, for example when using react-native-fs with Visual Studio Code + Windows? I've seen dozens examples with MacOs or XCode, but I'm not using either of these. I've got VSCode + Windows 10 + Expo app.

Details:

- The app is for iOS only.
- I'm only starting with the react-native development.
- We are using an Expo app for development.
- Created an app using `create-react-app-native`.
  `react-native link` and `react-native link react-native-fs` don't not seem to do anything:

`> react-native link react-native-fs`

`Scanning folders for symlinks in D:\Delete\o365app\nodemodules (65ms)_`

For some reason, `require('react-native').NativeModules` contains an empty `{}` object:

- `RNFSManager` is undefined

  [image]

More info:

- "expo": "^27.0.1",
- "react": "16.3.1",
- "react-native": "~0.55.2",
- "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.4",
- "react-native-fs": "^2.10.14",
- "react-navigation": "^2.5.5",

I'm probably missing something basic or obvious, but what is it? Can someone point me to an article or to the example that *actually* works with Windows+VSCode+Expo app, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad news for those using Windows and react-native.

We cannot develop iOS apps using Windows. I mean none of the native modules are available when using Windows. Basically, you can toy around a little bit on Windows, but you can't develop any real apps.

When you eject react-native app using `yarn run` --> `eject` there is no way to eject the app for iOS.
This is what I get when ejecting on Windows:

`Skipping iOS because you are not running macOS.`

Comment: Yeah, to add on, it's because you literally cannot build the app on Windows. Apple only offers the iOS SDK and build tools for macOS, so you can't compile any of the code for your app. When you link dependencies with react-native, it links the react-native iOS and Android specific files to their respective native projects. If you don't have macOS, you can't locally build an iOS app. You can develop for Android, though. :/

Comment: I have the same issue developing in Mac and opening my expo app with iPad...:(  This mean that I have Xcode bad configured and I can't access to the native modules?! Thank you so much!